# How to store details of dynamically generated check boxes in mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to do attendance app in android.When user enters the section in edit text component the list of the students are dynamically generated from the mysql database along with check boxes(check boxes don't have id) which are already checked.When user unchecked the check box the student have to be stored as absent otherwise the student have to be stored as present.Can anyone help me how to implement the code for storing the details of check boxes(i.e., present or absent) in mysql database.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class main extends ListActivity implements android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    SQLiteDatabase dBase;
    private CheckBox checkBox1
    ListView lv;
     ArrayList<Student>studentList;
    StudentAdapter slAdapter;
    private  Context context; 
     String returnString;

    private String URL_ITEMS;

    private String section;

    ProgressDialog progressdialog;


    private static final String TAG_FIXTURE = "fixture";
        private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

        JSONArray matchFixture = null;// to store the result of MySQL query after decoding JSON
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> matchFixtureList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);




        // GET THE DATA FROM OLD INTENT
        Intent previous = getIntent();
        section = previous.getStringExtra("section");
        Log.i("Section: ", " " + section);

        // Now generate the URL
        URL_ITEMS = "http://10.0.2.2/attend/getFixture.php?section=" + section;

        new GetFixture().execute();
}



    // declare parameters that are passed to PHP script i.e. the name "section" and its value submitted by user   
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    private class GetFixture extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(main.this);
            progressdialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
            progressdialog.setMessage("Getting Information from Server");
            progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressdialog.show();


        }
        @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {
            ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
            Log.d("url: ", "> " + URL_ITEMS);
            String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_ITEMS,ServiceHandler.GET);
            // print the json response in the log
            Log.d("main.class", " Get match fixture response: > " + json);
            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d("try", "in the try");
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    matchFixture = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FIXTURE);
                    Log.d("json aray", "user point array");
                    int len = matchFixture.length();
                    Log.d("len", "get array length");


                    if(matchFixture.length() == 0) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(main.this, "No Data Available for Section " + section, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });
                    }



                    for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        Log.d("id", id);

                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        Log.d("name", name);

                        //  hashmap for single match
                        HashMap<String, String> matchFixture = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        matchFixtureList.add(matchFixture);
                    }
                }

                catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("catch", "in the catch");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            else {
                 Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
                Toast.makeText(main.this, "Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    return null;
}
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    main.this, matchFixtureList,
                    R.layout.list1_item, new String[] {
        TAG_ID, TAG_NAME          }
    , new int[] {
        R.id.id,R.id.name

    }
    );
    setListAdapter(adapter);

  //  lv.setAdapter(adapter);

//lv.setAdapter(slAdapter);
    if(progressdialog.isShowing()) {
        progressdialog.dismiss();
    }
}
    }
    @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Toast.makeText(main.this, "into the on checked change listener..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if(pos !=ListView.INVALID_POSITION){

                for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) {


                     JSONObject c = null;
                    try {
                        c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     String id = null;
                    try {
                        id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     String name = null;
                    try {
                        name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        SQLiteDatabase database = openOrCreateDatabase("ORCL", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS attendance(id integer primary key autoincrement,name VARCHAR(150),id INT(10)");
                                database.execSQL("INSERT INTO attendance(name,id) VALUES('" + name + "'," + id+");");
                                Toast.makeText(main.this, "record inserted..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                database.close();
                }


                                                       }
    }



        /** You can not insert empty values and you should create Database and tables first **/


    //ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
//  dBase.insert("attendance", null, values);
//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Inserted..", 2000).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use setTag() and getTag() methods for identifying the checkboxes.

   ```
          // set the ID before rendering
         chcekbox.setTag(ID);

         // get the ID when this method called "onCheckedChanged"(before storing into the database)
         buttonView.getTag();
   ```

Comment: In my code Student name and check boxes are dynamically generated from the mysql database. Then how can i use setTag() and getTag() in my code.